# Change array string value from another array with index

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am trying to change my string value in an array after shuffling another array, how am i to do this?

Example:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

var stringarray = ["\\(array1[0]) = 1") 

array1.shuffle()

print(stringarray)
```

How am i to change the original stringarray value to the new shuffled value?

Thank you

The task:

```
    @IBAction func nextQuestion(_ sender: Any) {

    if levelSelected == 1 {
        questionLabel.text = standardRules.randomElement()
    }
    players.shuffle()
    print(players)
```

standardRules has a string value that takes the value of players[0]

Essentially what i am trying to do is this:

I am trying to grab 2 random values that are not the same in a string like this

```
    var players = ["Jack, John, Michael, Peter"]
    var playersArray = ["\(players.randomElement) and \(players.randomElement) has to battle")
```

How am i to do this, so it grabs 2 different values?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe it worth to show us the exact task?

Comment: What do you need `stringArray` to show? Also change the 2nd line in the code you posted to a more accurate example.

Comment: So what should be changed in the end after players.shuffle()? The text on questionLabel?

Comment: Yes, questionLabel.text should be the new value from the element in standardRules which is an array, with value like this: 

standardRules = ["\(players[0]) has to do this"]


Then i want a new value after shuffling the players array

Comment: As already mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026461/grab-2-randomelements-that-are-not-the-same) consider that `players` contains **one** item, a string with some names comma separated.

Comment: That's a mistake though, it is supposed to be

        var players = ["Jack", "John", "Michael", "Peter"]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some core concepts of the Swift language. When you create your `stringarray` it makes a call of `array1.description` and stores the result into an array. From that point any modifications of the original array will not change anything in `stringarray`.

So if you want to pick two different players from an array you need to do something like that:

```
let index1 = Int.random(in: (0 ..< players.count))
var index2: Int
repeat {
    index2 = Int.random(in: (0 ..< players.count))
} while index1 == index2
let matchText = "\(players[index1]) and \(players[index2] has to battle)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try replacing:

```
var stringarray = ["\\(array1[0]) = 1") 

array1.shuffle()
```

with:

```
var stringarray = array1.shuffle()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it very easy by this code :

```
var players = ["Jack", "John", "Michael", "Peter"]

// get the first random element
var random1 = players.randomElement()

//delete that element so you can't duplicate it 
players = players.filter{$0 != random1}

//get your second radom element
var random2 = players.randomElement()

//add your element again
players.append(random1!)
```